# why can't the compiler bind a const int to an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Here is a subset of my code. Why can't it bind a `const int` to an rvalue reference? What I expect is that `T` will be deduced as `int const &` and the type of `e` as `int const & &&` will be folded to `int const &`.

```
template <typename T>
List<T>::List(initializer_list<T> il)
{
    for (T const & i : il) insertAsLast(i);
}

template <typename T>
ListNode<T> * List<T>::insertAsLast(T && e)
{
    ++_size; return trailer->insertAsPrev(std::forward<T>(e));
}

template <typename T>
ListNode<T> * ListNode<T>::insertAsPrev(T && e)
{
    pnode node = new ListNode<T>(std::forward<T>(e), prev, this);
    prev->next = node; prev = node;
    return node;
}

int main()
{
    List<int> l = {1, 3, 2, 1, 34, 5, 2, 34, , 4};
}
```

error:

> can't bind a const int to a rvalue reference

Comment: Where is 'insertAsLast' template?

Comment: updated @lgor R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and the type of e `int const & &&` will be folded to `int const &`.

No, here's no [reference collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340092/3309790). `T &&` becomes [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) only when it's the template parameter of the function template, but `T` seems to be the template parameter of the class template `List`; then `T&&` is just the rvalue-reference here.

Making `List<T>::insertAsLast` template would solve the problem, but whether it's the correct solution depends on your design.

```
template <typename T>
template <typename X>
ListNode<T> * List<T>::insertAsLast(X && e)
{
    ++_size; return trailer->insertAsPrev(std::forward<X>(e));
}
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion. and now I meet another problem.

Comment: @BAKEZQ If this answer addressed the initial issue you were having, make sure to mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark. If you have another problem, you should create a new question for it, rather than reusing this one.