# Universal reference l-value not copying object

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, lvalue, forwarding-reference

Why these asserts work for the below code? The universal reference should bind to l-value reference `run(T& a)`, and copy an object `b` from `a`. However both objects addresses "a" and "b" are the same in the `run()` function. Tested with C++11/14/17/2a gcc-9.2 and clang++-6.0. What part of the standard says this is valid? did not find anything related.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void run(T&& a)
{
  T b {std::forward<T>(a)};
  ++b;
  assert(b == a);
  assert(&a == &b);
}

int main()
{
  int value {10};
  run(value); // asserts work, not expected
  // run(std::move(value)); // the asserts don't work as expected
}
```

Comment: see this [link](https://foonathan.net/2016/11/template-argument-deduction/), helped me a lot

Comment: It has good examples, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However both objects addresses "a" and "b" are the same in the `run()` function.

When being passed an lvalue, `T` is [deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) as lvalue-reference, i.e. `int&`. (`int& &&` [collapses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30340092/3309790) to `int&`, so the type of function parameter `a` is `int&`.) Then `b` is declared as a reference binding to `a`.

When being passed an rvalue, `T` is deduced as `int`. (So the type of function parameter `a` is `int&&`.) Then `b` is declared as an independent variable copied from `a`.

Comment: That's interesting. I was not expecting the type `T` to change, but instead the type of the argument. Semantic wise, is clear the template <typename T> is not a reference.

Comment: @AdvSphere, `&&` is an rvalue reference. A forwarding reference (universal reference) isn't truly its own entity, just the result of `& &&` becoming `&` and `&& &&` (or `<no reference> &&`) becoming `&&`.

Comment: @AdvSphere The type of `T` changes, which yields the change of the function parameter type.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification did some more reading and makes sense. std::forward<T> needs to include the `&` for lvalue, therefore the whole deduction of type `T` for the function includes the reference.

Comment: @AdvSphere Yes, forwarding reference and `std::forward` have to work together; then we can forward arguments reserving their value categories.

Answer (score 1):

In `run(value)`, `value` is an lvalue, and it needs to match with `T&&`. Lvalues cannot bind to rvalue references, so `T = int` and `T = int&&` won’t do, as then `T&& = int&&`. The only thing that works is `T = int&`. Due to reference collapsing, an rvalue reference to lvalue reference is an lvalue reference, so the instantiation of `run` looks like:

```
template<>
void run<int&>(int &a) {
    int &b{a}; // expanding std::forward
    ++b;
    assert(b == a);
    assert(&b == &a);
}
```

Obviously, the assertions always pass. Now, for `run(std::move(value))`, the argument is indeed an rvalue, and you get `T = int`. Then

```
template<>
void run<int>(int &&a) {
    int b{std::move(a)};
    ++b;
    assert(b == a);
    assert(&b == &a);
}
```

This of course fails. Perhaps you should replace

```
T b{std::forward<T>(a)};
```

with

```
std::decay_t<T> b{std::forward<T>(a)};
```

This will remove references from `T` (ensuring `b` is a new (copied/moved) object) and also handle arrays and functions (by making `b` a pointer even if `a` isn’t).

Doubt you need them, but [`[temp.deduct.call]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#call-3) talks about the template deduction of forwarding references, and [`[dcl.init.list]/3.9`](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-3.9) says that list-initializing a reference just binds it to the element of initializer list. Also [`[forward]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/forward), well, explains `std::forward<T>`. Basically, if `T` is an lvalue reference, then `std::forward<T>(x)` is an lvalue, and otherwise an xvalue (a kind of rvalue). (Basically it’s a conditional `std::move`.)

Comment: If all you need is a copy, `auto b = a;` seems the most straightforward choice. That does the decay without having to be explicit.