# RVALUE reference variables and rvalue reference variables returned by the function

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void fcn(int&& a) { }
```

```
int&& reti() {
    return 3;
}
```

```
int main() {
    int&& a = 3;
    fcn(a);    //error
    fcn(reti()); //right
    return 0;
}
```

why does the first call generate an error, but the second call does not? they are all the `int&&` type.

Comment: Rule-of-thumb if it has a name it's an lvalue.

Comment: `a` in `fcn(a)` is an lvalue expression. There are plenty of dupes for this.

Comment: Another [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339922/c-rvalue-references-in-function-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are different things. Even `a`'s type is rvalue-reference but as the name of variable `a` is an lvalue expression itself.

(emphasis mine)

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function`, a template parameter object (since C++20)`, or a data member, regardless of type, such as `std::cin`
>   or `std::endl`. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the   expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;

You can use `std::move` to convert it to rvalue as:

```
fcn(std::move(a));
```

On the other hand, `reti` returns rvalue-reference and `reti()` is an rvalue expression. (PS: `reti()` always returns a dangling reference.)

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;

Comment: Doesn't reti() also a variable of type int&&?

Comment: Isn't also `a` in function `main` dangling? Or does bounding (temporary) `3` to a r-value reference extend its lifetime?

Comment: @air No, it's an xvalue (rvalue) expression.

Comment: @paolo Yes, lifetime gets extended to the lifetime of `a`, i.e. in the scope of `main()`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks. I knew this is the case with l-value refernces to `const`; I wasn't aware it also applies to r-value references.

Comment: @paolo Yes, same life-extension rule as lvalue-reference to `const`.

Comment: I would also distinguish between types of `a` the variable and `a` the expression. Expressions can't have reference types.