# Mistake with bind in "The C++ Programming Language [4th Edition] - Bjarne Stroustrup"

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

I found this code in Bjarne Stroustrup's book:
[image: Page screenshot]

The problem with this code is that variable `i` does not stay at 2, it is incremented to 3. You can check it here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/p5JC1nOA4pIpsgXb

We do not have to use the `std::ref()` to increment this variable. Is it a mistake in the book or something has been changed since C++11?

Comment: God, that font is horrible..

Comment: Have you checked the errata?  http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html

Comment: @RichardCritten there seems to be no mention of `std::bind`

Comment: god, that's not font - all i look like l. typography snafu?

Comment: The linked page does not contain any code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The example is incorrect, `bind` does make a copy of its arguments unless you wrap it in `std::reference_wrapper` as the text correctly says, but that's not what the example shows. In the example, the argument `i` is passed to the functor returned by `bind`, not to `bind` itself. If the example had instead been the following, the value of `i` would've remained `2`.

```
auto inc = bind(incr, i);   // a copy of i is made
inc(); // i stays 2; inc(i) incremented a local copy of i
```

In the example shown in the book, the argument `i` will be forwarded to `incr`, which will result in an lvalue reference to the original `i` being passed to the function, and the original `i` will be incremented.

For the relevant standard quotes, from *23.14.11.3 
[[func.bind.bind]](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.bind.bind)/10*

> The values of the bound arguments `v1`, `v2`, …, `vN` and their corresponding types `V1`, `V2`, …, `VN` depend on the types `TDi` derived from the call to `bind` and the cv-qualifiers *cv* of the call wrapper `g` as follows:
>   ...
>   — if the value `j` of `is_­placeholder_­v<TDi>` is not zero, the argument is `std​::​forward<Uj>(uj)` and its type `Vi` is `Uj&&`;

Comment: I deleted my answer cause I think you're right, so let me move this question over here: The functor created by `bind` should have the function: `void operator() (int&& arg) const { incr(arg); }` So passing a local `int` to a function expecting an `int&&` should have the effect of passing by reference?

Comment: @JonathanMee No, if that were the signature `inc(i)` would not compile because you would be trying to bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference. The signature is `template <typename T> void operator(T&& arg) { incr(std::forward<T>(arg)); }`. So the example forwards a reference to the original `i` to `incr`.

Comment: So when passing `i` into a function that accepts an `int&&`, `arg` will actually be an `int&`? That is to say, when `arg` is forwarded to `incr`, it is an `int&` that's being forwarded?

Comment: @JonathanMee The `_N` placeholders do perfect forwarding, which means the value category of the original argument is preserved. If `incr` was defined as `void incr(int&&)` and you tried to call `inc(i)` it wouldn't compile because you would be attempting to bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference parameter. You would have to write `inc(std::move(i))` in that case.

Comment: OK, what am I missing? You say that the functor operator takes an `int&&` and `i` is passed to it, but if `incr` took an `int&&` we couldn't pass `i` to it. Seems like one of those has to be wrong.

Comment: I don't see where I've said it takes an `int&&`. If you mean the `T&&` in `template <typename T> void operator()(T&&)`, then that's a [forwarding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14302849/241631), previously known as a universal reference. When you pass `i` (an lvalue) to it, `T` will be deduced as `int&`, reference collapsing happens and the parameter type is `int&`.

Comment: so, book example was unnecessary overcomplicated with placeholder which actualy serves to same purpose as std::ref in this case

Comment: Did you email Mr. Stroustrup about the error? (also +1 of course)

Comment: @Barry I'd assumed the OP would do it, but I just sent him an email. Thanks for the reminder.