# Why auto&& can bind lvalue while int&& cannot?

Tags: c++

Why this is allowed:

```
int a = 0;
auto&& b = a;
```

while this is not:

```
int a = 0;
int&& b = a;
```

I understand that an l-value cannot be bound to an r-value reference, so why (or how) in this specific case auto&& differs from int&& ?

Comment: `int&&` and `T&&` are two different things

Comment: I know I wanted to generalize with T I mean every kind of defined type.

Comment: `int&&` is an `rvalue` while `auto&&` is a `forwarding` reference. Reference collapsing takes place for `auto&&` while `int&& b` is expecting a `rvalue` reference. If you cast `a` to an `rvalue` it'll work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for universal references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302849/syntax-for-universal-references) (`auto&&` is basically `template <typename T>` + `T&&`)