# Is it meaningless to declare the return type of a function as T&&?

Tags: c++, c++11, return-type, rvalue-reference, temporary

As we have known, in most common cases, `T&&` means "this is a temporary object". However, if one wants to return a temporary object from a function, he/she can declare the function as follows:

```
template<class T>
T f()
{
    T t;
    ......

    return t;
}
```

or (Note: Not Correct)

```
template<class T>
T&& f()
{
    T t;
    ......

    return t;
}
```

But I think the latter is overdid, because the former is enough and backward compatible.

Yet, I also find the `std::forward()`'s return type is declared as T&&, so I'm sure my understanding about this is incomplete.

My real question is: When and where should we declare the return type of a function as T&&?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-mean-in-c11

Comment: In one short rule of thumb: only "move" and "forward" are allowed to return `T&&`. (for the picky: I am using "move" and "forward" in a vague sense that includes things like `op*` from move-iterators, for example)

Comment: Related: Scott Meyer's [Universal References](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: "*As we have known, T&& means "this is a temporary object".*" We most certainly do *not* know that. Because that's not true.

Comment: *"However, if one wants to return a temporary object from a function, he/she can declare the function as follows"* - No, they can't (at least the second version with the `&&`). `&&` is (or can mean) **reference** to temporary. Don't return references to local variables. This holds for rvalue-references the same like it used to hold for lvalue-references ever since.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your example, the `T&&` is wrong, it's a dangling reference.

But `std::forward` doesn't return an rvalue reference to a local variable in its own definition, it returns an rvalue reference to its by-rvalue-reference argument (or an lvalue reference to a by-lvalue-reference argument).

You should return an rvalue reference only if you want the caller of your function to be able to move from whatever that reference refers to.

Normally that will only be if the purpose of the function is to provide move access to some significant object (perhaps which already exists). So that includes `std::move` (which allows you to move from an lvalue), and similarly you might write an accessor function specifically designed for users to move from a data member of some object, or an element of some container. If the object itself isn't significant, only the value, then you can return by value.

As grizzly says, sometimes due to reference collapsing you can take advantage of tricks which mean that you *type* `T&&` in your code, but when `T` is already an lvalue-reference type `T&&` is the same lvalue reference type. `std::forward` uses that trick. That is to say, because of reference collapsing `T&&` doesn't mean "rvalue reference to T", it means "T if T is a reference type, otherwise rvalue reference to T".

Comment: Good answer! The first sentence clearly classified the differences between the two examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`T&&` doesn't necessarily mean that the result is an rvalue. When used with a template parameter `&&` denotes a universal reference, which can either be an rvalue or an lvalue reference. More specifically: If `T` is an lvalue reference type `foo&`, `T&&` is actually an lvalue refere to `foo`, otherwise it denotes an rvalue reference.

This can be used to write functions, which take any kind of argument:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T&&);
bar a;
const bar b;
foo(a);//T and T&& will both be bar&
foo(b);//T and T&& will both be const bar&
foo(bar());//T will be bar, T&& will be bar&&
```

With this in mind `std::forward` is called with a `T&` and casts it to `T&&`, where `T` is explicitly stated. So if the original function parameter was an lvalue reference, it will return one, otherwise it will return an rvalue reference, enabling perfect forwarding.

As for when to use it as a return type: Rarely, though it might be useful to avoid copies when arguments are passed through, for example:

```
template<typename T> T&& foo(T&& bar) {/*some ops*/ return std::forward<T>(bar);}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether your function is a template function or not. In your question it was, but let's first take a look at if it isn't:

**Non-Template**

`T&&` is not meaningless as a return type. The reason is that it, in fact, does not mean "temporary object". It means "rvalue reference". The difference is subtle, but can be highlighted with a class of functions for which this return type is relevant. Namely, what if we want to return a reference, to an rvalue, but the object it refers to is not a local object of our function?

```
T&& return_rvalue(/*some data*/)
{
   T&& t = Get_a_reference();
   // Do something fascinating.
   return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

One very special case of this pattern is the function `std::move`, which takes any reference and returns it a corresponding rvalue reference. Naturally, in real code, you should of course use `std::move` rather than performing the cast directly, since this more clearly shows your intention.

**Template**

If `T` is a template parameter, `T&&` is what Scott Meyers refers to as a [Universal Reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). This means the type of `T&&` will be figured out using reference collapsing... In short, it means `T&&` is an rvalue if `T` i not a reference type, and an lvalue reference if it is..