# overload of std::unordered_map::insert reloaded

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [my previous question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721395/overload-of-stdunordered-mapinsert),

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> std::unordered_map::insert(const value_type&)
```

is useful than

```
template<class P>
std::pair<iterator, bool> std::unordered_map::insert(P&&)
```

for some situations like

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> v;
v.insert({"key", 1});
```

because the compiler cannot deduce `P` from `{"key", 1}`.  (Thanks [sellibitze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172531/sellibitze))

However, although this argument `{"key", 1}` (= `std::pair<std::string, int>("key", 1)`) is prvalue, it cannot move to the container because the argument type is `const value_type&`.

My question is --- I am sorry to be persistent --- why the standard choose `const value_type&` for the argument type instead of `value_type&&`?  Or, are there any other reasons that the function with an argument type `const value_type&` exists and the function with an argument type `value_type&&` does not exist?

Edit:
I created a sample.

- With an argument type `const value_type&` like unordered_map: http://ideone.com/GB72fc.
- With an argument type `value_type&&` only: http://ideone.com/dXnQJr.
- With both argument types: http://ideone.com/shAb9e.

Comment: The missing `value_type&&` overload of `insert` was likely an oversight, as with `make_unique`.

Comment: The absence of `make_unique` was deliberate too.  Though I've no objection to it being in a future standard.  For C++11 there were not enough people sufficiently expert in `unique_ptr` to answer questions like:  what do you do with the custom deleter?  With array types?  And I was spread too thin to push it.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance you might want to use emplace -- possibly using pair's "pairwise constructor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "missing" `value_type&&` overload of `insert` for (`unordered_`)(`multi`)`map` is intentional.  `value_type` is a `pair<const key_type, value_type>`.  The `const` on the `key_type` pretty much rains on the move-semantics parade.

I really wanted to allow moving from a `pair<key_type, value_type>`, and thus the introduction of the `P&&` overload.  In hindsight, that may not have been the best solution.  However it was a deliberate design decision.

At the time that decision was made, the uniform initialization proposal had not come up.  And so the interaction with that was never thoroughly investigated prior to standardization (just not enough time/manpower).

The `const value_type&` overload comes from C++98, and it was never a consideration to remove or modify it.