# Template type deduction for stream manipulators

Tags: c++, templates, iostream, manipulators

I'm unsure as to whether this code will not compile.

The example code I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        Foo& operator<<(const T& t) {
            cout << t;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo << "Hello World"; // perfectly fine
    foo << endl; // shit hits the fan

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
test.cpp:19:12: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘foo << std::endl’
test.cpp:19:12: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:10:14: note: template<class T> Foo& Foo::operator<<(const T&)
test.cpp:10:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:19:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
```

I'm confused as to why it cannot substitute the function type of `endl` (`ostream& (*)(ostream&)`) for `T`, where it clearly is fine with doing it when you specify `cout << endl;`

I find it additionally puzzling that this fixes the problem [ edited ]

```
Foo& operator<<(ostream& (*f)(ostream&)) {
    cout << f;
    return *this;
}
```

In case the question isn't clear, I'm asking why it could not deduce the template in the first place.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Any particular reason you're not deriving from `std::basic_ostream<C,CT>` or implementing a streambuf?

Comment: To the last question: It couldn't deduce the template in the first place, because **multiple overloads** were applicable - hence the function-reference case was ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`endl` is a manipulator, i.e. it's an *unresolved function type*. There are several overloads, and the type deduction is unable to decide which one you want.

More specificly, here's what `endl` looks like (in GNU libc++):

```
/**
 *  @brief  Write a newline and flush the stream.
 *
 *  This manipulator is often mistakenly used when a simple newline is
 *  desired, leading to poor buffering performance.  See
 *  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt11ch25s02.html
 *  for more on this subject.
*/
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
  inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
  endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
  { return flush(__os.put(__os.widen('\n'))); }
```

**Updated** So, the problem is, the compiler cannot *deduce* which *instance of `endl`* you would be passing (it's an unresolved overload). ***You might work around this by doing a `static_cast<ostream&(*)(ostream&)>(endl)` instead.***

Of course, that's not convenient. Here's a simple fix: [http://liveworkspace.org/code/2F2VHe$1](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2F2VHe%241)

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo : public std::ostream
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        Foo& operator<<(T&& t) {
            cout << std::forward<T>(t);
            return *this;
        }

        typedef std::ostream& (manip)(std::ostream&);

        Foo& operator<<(manip& m) {
            cout << m;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo << "Hello World"; // perfectly fine
    foo << endl; // everything is fine

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain further, is the reason because it doesn't actually try the different overload substitutions to determine the correct one? Or am I expecting too much from the compiler

Comment: @AnthonySottile I provided a simple sample of how to cater for manipulator `endl`: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2F2VHe$1

Comment: Could you embellish on the differences between your code and the code I had above and the reasons for the differences.  For instance, my current "solution" does the same thing with explicitly defining the overload for the manipulator -- but could you explain the use of `std::forward`.  Also could you explain the reasoning behind why the compiler is unable to choose the overload without that explicit definition.

Comment: @AnthonySottile Ah sorry, `std::forward` is part of perfect forwarding and it's not essential to the issue. I guess it's the force of habit I wrote that :) See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5481588/85371

Comment: I embellished on the explanation of `endl` as a _manipulator_, **and** answered your last question explicitely.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Whoops. I didn't actually try that one out :). I 'fixed' it by asking for a function pointer (would a `ostream&(&)(ostream&)` have been ok?)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `endl` is a manipulator defined as a *function template*. Paragraph 27.7.1 of the C++11 Standard specifies its signature:

```
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
template <class charT, class traits>
```

Moreover, per Paragraph 13.3.1 on overload resolution:

> In each case where a candidate is a function template, **candidate function template specializations are generated using template argument deduction** (14.8.3, 14.8.2). Those candidates are then handled as candidate functions in the usual way.

Your `operator <<` is a defined as a template, and the compiler needs to deduce the type of `T`. However, how can the compiler know which instantiation of `endl` you meant? How can it deduce the template arguments `charT` and `traits`? There is nothing else in your call to `operator <<` from which it could be deduced.

You have two ways out of this problem. Either you cast the type of `endl` explicitly, to tell the compiler which overload shall be picked:

```
foo << (std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))endl;
```

Or, as you did, you create an overload of `operator <<` which accepts a function with that specific signature. Your compiler will now select it:

```
Foo& operator<<(ostream& (*f)(ostream&)) 
{
    return *this << f;
}
```

Inside this function definition there is no ambiguity as to what `f` is: its type is precisely defined. However, be careful here: this function doesn't likely do what you expect! In fact, it just keeps calling itself, generating an **infinite recursion**!

Therefore, this assertion:

> [...] note I'm actually calling my other method implementation:

Is **incorrect**: you're not calling the other method implementation, you keep calling the same function over and over again.

Comment: shoot, good catch, I probably should have ran my code instead of just checking it compiles...