# How should be function pointer or function object passed?

Tags: c++

Every time I see function taking `function` as template parameter, it takes `function` object by value.

E.g. from  [for_each reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    fn (*first);
    ++first;
  }
  return fn;      // or, since C++11: return move(fn);
}
```

1) Why is that?

There are many things you can pass inside, raw function, lambda function, std::function, functor... So object can be quite large (especially std::function or custom functor) and  passing by value is not ideal. But reference says, that `fn` must be `function pointer or a move constructible function object`.

```
struct FunctorNMC //non-move-constructible
{
    FunctorNMC() = default;
    FunctorNMC(FunctorNMC&&) = delete;

    void operator()(int a) const { std::cout << a << " ";   }
};
```

cannot call like:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), FunctorNMC());
```

in VS2013 can be called like:

```
FunctorNMC tmp;
my_for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), tmp);
```

but [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NOBpNk) gives error.

2) Why is that? What if I have functor, which for some reason don't support `move`?

3) Shouldn't be function taken as something like `Function && fn`?

4) Can be function object passed by value (without moving)?

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NOBpNk) project to play around if needed.

Comment: That code fails to compile because explicitly declaring a move constructor causes the implicitly defined copy constructor to be deleted. If you supply a copy constructor then it should work. Anyway, I'm having a hard time seeing why you would ever want to make a functor that can be neither copied nor moved.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5481588/3537339

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does T&& (double ampersand) mean in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11)