# Variadic Functions- When Should I use &&... vs &...?

Tags: c++, function, variadic

I've been trying to understand the difference between `Ts&&...` and `Ts&...` for variadic functions, but can't find any explanations.

What are the differences between the two, and when would I use one over the other?

Comment: A single `&` is a parameter passed by reference. The latter is an [`rvalue` reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11)

Comment: @Cyber In the special case of `T&&` where `T` is deduced, it can also bind to an lvalue (because the `T` can be deduced to `U&`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as the difference between `T&` and `T&&`.

`Ts&...` only binds to lvalues. `Ts&&...` binds to both lvalues and rvalues and can be used to implement perfect forwarding.

Usually you'll probably want `Ts&&...` since it's hard to imagine why a function should be specified to accept arbitrarily many lvalues of arbitrary type, but not any rvalues. Functions that contain a `Ts&&...` are usually functions like `emplace` member functions that forward all the arguments to another function, such as a constructor.

Comment: A typesafe version of `printf` would be one case where you might prefer to take the arguments by `const &`... Otherwise you might end up with bloated executables: `safe_printf("%d\n", 1); int a = 5; safe_print("%d\n", a);` would have two overloads if the argument is `T&&` but only one if it is `T&`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Good point! But at least `const Ts&...` binds to rvalues too :-)

Comment: I'm now more confused and still not sure as to when I should choose to use Ts&&... over Ts&...!

Comment: @user3791372 Why don't you tell us what kind of function you're writing?

Comment: I did a lot of reading about Ts&& vs T& today, and I think I now understand. general rule to use && over & as it allows data to be passed around destructively and will be faster as it doesn't invoke constructor copy's as far as I understand.