# Can bind a (non const) l-value reference to an r-value in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, rvalue-reference

[One of the answers in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11) states that we cannot bind a non const l-value reference to an r-value. This is a sample code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Position2D
{
    float m_x;
    float m_y;

    Position2D(float x, float y) : m_x(x), m_y(y)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Position2D& p2 = Position2D(2, 2); // this is the line which has the problem.
    Position2D&& p3 = Position2D(2, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is Visual Studio 2013 compiler compiles above mentioned code segment without any error. But [online c++11 compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) shows an error as the [link which included in SO answer](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html) describes. Who is correct? Is there any problem in Visual Studio 2013 C++ compiler with new C++11 standards?

Comment: MSVC has a long-standing misfeature that permits binding temporaries to non-const reference, in violation of the standard. You can use `/Za` option to disable it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks. Now I got expected compilation error