# Passing a temporary as a reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently trying to understand the copy and swap idiom through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). The answer posted has the following code in it

```
class dumb_array
{
public:
    // ...

    friend void swap(dumb_array& first, dumb_array& second) // nothrow
    {
        // enable ADL (not necessary in our case, but good practice)
        using std::swap; 

        // by swapping the members of two classes,
        // the two classes are effectively swapped
        swap(first.mSize, second.mSize); 
        swap(first.mArray, second.mArray);
    }

    // move constructor
    dumb_array(dumb_array&& other)
        : dumb_array() // initialize via default constructor, C++11 only
    {
        swap(*this, other); //<------Question about this statement
    }

    // ...
};
```

I noticed that the author used this statement

```
swap(*this, other);
```

`other` is a temporary or a `rvalue` which is being passed as a reference to the method swap.   I was not sure if we could pass a rvalue by reference.
In order to test this I tried doing this however the following does not work until i convert the parameter to a `const reference`

```
void myfunct(std::string& f)
{
    std::cout << "Hello";
}

int main() 
{
   myfunct(std::string("dsdsd"));
}
```

My question is how can `other` being a temporary be passed by reference in   `swap(*this, other);` while `myfunct(std::string("dsdsd"));` cant be passed by reference.

Comment: I think you need to understand what an rvalue reference is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5481588/4342498

Comment: `swap(*this, other);` is wrong. It has to be `swap(*this, std::move(other));` (other is a named variable)

Comment: @DieterLücking in that case swap method wont work as it requires a reference and you are passing a temporary. It would only work as you suggested if it was a constant reference. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Please have a look at : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: @DieterLücking Why do you think `swap` would expect an rvalue argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor takes a rvalue reference, but `other` is a lvalue (it has a name).

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  So other basically holds an rvalue but is itself an lvalue. Am i correct ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: I think it's slightly more accurate to say the reference is an lvalue that is _constructed from_ an rvalue.  (references aren't truely "constructed", but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of:

```
myfunct(std::string("dsdsd"));
```

The value `std::string("dsdsd")` is a temporary within a scope that the call to `myfunct()` is actually outside of.

C++ explicitly specifies that binding the reference to const extends the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself.