# Understanding C++ function pointer pass by reference in HIP

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, hip

[HIP](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP) is the AMD GPU programming model corresponding to the NVIDIA's CUDA. I have a [code snippet](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP/blob/32787fa1fc4a34e1afd6bb1c55e1973b3bb4eeaf/include/hip/hcc_detail/hip_runtime.h#L343) from HIP source code that I can't fully understand. As a reminder, the understanding of the following code snippnet doesn't require any background knowledge of HIP, but more of a question in C++ template/function pointer.

```
typedef int hipLaunchParm;    
template <typename... Args, typename F = void (*)(hipLaunchParm, Args...)>
inline void hipLaunchKernel(F&& kernel, const dim3& numBlocks, const dim3& dimBlocks,
                        std::uint32_t groupMemBytes, hipStream_t stream, Args... args) 
{
    hipLaunchKernelGGL(kernel, numBlocks, dimBlocks, groupMemBytes, stream, 
        hipLaunchParm{}, std::move(args)...);
}
```

I'm confused about the following:

- If F is a function pointer, why does it need to be double referenced in the argument?
- How is the first template argument `typename... Args` useful?
- hipLaunchParm is just an alias for integer, but what is the meaning of {} when it is called in the argument?

Comment: What is "HIP"???

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hip is the AMD corresponding GPU programming model for CUDA https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That should have been *in the question*. Don't make assumptions that people reading your question know your domain or acronyms. Make the question contain *all* relevant information.

Comment: Can you deeplink the actual source file as well?

Comment: *What is "HIP"???* To be square, of course.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for reminding, question updated. I should probably avoid mentioned HIP cuz the question has less to do with anything technical related with HIP but more with C++

Comment: I would leave the HIP. It provides useful context.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Sure, I added a deeplink in the description. Thanks for the Variadic_template link, that is a major gap in understanding how the code works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If F is a function pointer, why does it need to be double referenced in the argument?

F isn't a function pointer necessarily. That is just the default type. You can pass any<sup>†</sup> callable as long as it is invokable with the given arguments, and you want to avoid copying stateful function objects when that's not necessary. Some might not even be copyable. That may be the reason why they use a reference here.

<sup>†</sup> as far as C++ is concerned. I don't know about restrictions that HIP / CUDA might have.

> How is the first template argument `typename... Args` useful?

It allows passing a variable number of arguments into the delegated function.

> hipLaunchParm is just a alias for integer, but what is the meaning of {} when it is called in the argument?

`T{}` is a syntax for value initialisation of a temporary. In case of integer, this means that zero is passed as an argument.

Comment: Now it looks like my gap is in understanding of c++11 features. The first one is about more generic nature of rvalue reference. Second one is variadic template. Third one is initializer list.

Comment: @jer_yin as far as the rvalue reference (technically forwarding reference, since the type is deduced) is concerned: I have no idea why they use that instead of a const lvalue reference.

Comment: I find a good resource [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11), that explains the benefit of rvalue reference versus const lvalue.

Comment: @jer_yin I know exactly what rvalue references are used for, but the code here shows no need to use it for the function argument.