# Is repeatedly calling move with rvalue references necessary?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

```
struct Bar
{    
   Bar(std::string&& val)
    : m_Val(std::move(val)) {} // A

  Bar& operator=(Bar&& _other) { m_Val = std::move(_other.m_Val); }
  std::string m_Val;
}

struct Foo
{
  void Func1(Bar&& param)
  {
     Func2(std::move(param)) // B
  }

  void Func2(Bar&& param)
  {
     m_Bar = std::move(param); // C
  }

  Bar m_Bar;
};

void main()
{
   Foo f;
   std::string s = "some str";
   Bar b(std::move(s));
   f.Func1(std::move(b));
}
```

Give that you're calling `move` in `main()` to invoke the rvalue reference methods, is it necessary in lines A & B & C to repeat an additional call to `move()`? You already have the rvalue reference, so is it doing anything different in those lines with vs without?

I understand in Bar's `operator=` it's necessary because you're technically moving the `m_Val` rather than `_other` itself correct?

Note: Originally, I was incorrectly calling rvalue references as rvalue parameters. My apologies. I've corrected that to make the question easier to find and make clearer.

Comment: I know you're probably doing this to make your point clear but note in your current example you don't need to write `Bar`'s move constructor at all.

Comment: There's no such thing as "rvalue parameter". A *named* reference makes an *lvalue* expression (yes, even a rvalue reference is an lvalue). So, in order to make it into an xvalue again you need to apply `std::move` again.

Comment: @AnT I'm still confused about what your profile picture is supposed to be.

Comment: @SombreroChicken - why is that? If I make the string in main, I don't need to move it? The whole thing, including String is contrived yeah, but my understanding is if I want to avoid copying it, I need to move it.

Comment: @AnT When I read about it in other SO's, theyre called "rvalue references". Sorry, I'll rename the question from Parameter to Reference.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11

Comment: @user99999991 SombreroChicken means that for this `struct` in your example compiler will generate proper move ctor and move assignment operator implicitly so it is not necessary to define them manually here.

Comment: @Slava oh! thank you

Comment: @Sombrero Chicken: I don't remember how and why I came up with that idea for an avatar. But anyway: http://babepka.com/gallery/albums/ritacm/ritacm_maiden1.jpg

Comment: Note that you hard-coded _moving_ of object contents. Sometimes, it's better to use moving only for rvalue arguments and copying for lvalue arguments. This is what _perfect forwarding_ is for. That is, forwarding references combined with `std::forward`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Give that you're calling `move` in `main()` to invoke the rvalue parameter methods, is it necessary in lines A & B & C to repeat an additional call to `move()`?

Yes.  What you call an *rvalue parameter* is actually an rvalue reference.  Just like a lvalue reference, it is an lvalue in the scope that it is being used.  That means you need to use `move` to cast it back into an rvalue so that it gets moved, instead of copied.  Remember, **if the object has a name, it is an lvalue**.

Comment: You'd improve this if you illustrated why.  Basically, because the parameter could be used more than once in the body of the function.

Comment: I did like you to make bold this; ***"..if the object has a name, it is an lvalue"*** ;. Because that's the key thing everyone should remember..