# Pass by value/reference for a parameter that will be moved within function

Tags: c++, move

If you have a function parameter that is intended to be moved into a variable within the function, would you have want to use pass by reference instead of pass by value?

For example, is there ever any benefit to using

```
void func(T &object2move)
{
  T obj{std::move(object2move)};
}
```

vs.

```
void func(T object2move)
{
  T obj{std::move(object2move)};
}
```

In addition to the above, is the only case where you want to use the following code when you only want `func` to take in an rvalue?

```
void func(T object2move)
{
  T obj{object2move};
}
```

Is the answer to these questions dependent on what `T` is?

Comment: `T &object2move` is would be misleading, because when passing an lvalue to a function (without `std::move`), one doesn't normally expect it to be moved from. Also it doesn't let you pass rvalues.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think the choice of duplicate is very poor! That target doesn't mention r-value references, which would be an ideal solution here: `void func(T&& object2move)`. If you want to keep it closed, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11) is a 'better dupe'. Personally, I think it should be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function will definitely move from the given value, then the best way to express this is by taking an rvalue-reference parameter (`T&&`). This way, if the user tries to pass an lvalue directly, they will get a compile error. And that forces them to invoke `std::move` directly on the lvalue, which *visibly* indicates to the reader that the value will be moved-from.

Using an lvalue-reference is always wrong. Lvalue-references don't bind to xvalues and prvalues (ie: expressions where it's OK to move from them), so you're kind of lying with such an interface.