# Are the following 3 ways to define objects identical?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, construction

In my understanding the following are identical:

```
Person p{}; // Case 1
Person p = {}; // Case 1.5
```

I noticed

```
Person p = Person{}; // Case 2
```

produces the same tracing output as the `Case 1` and `Case 1.5` above.

- Question 1: Comparing case 2 with either case 1 or case 1.5, is it because of copy elision or something else?
- Question 2: What are the differences between the following?

```
Person p{};            // Case 1
Person p = Person{};   // Case 2
Person&& p = Person{}; // Case 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does T&& (double ampersand) mean in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11)

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot: It doesn't answer OP's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three statements are not entirely identical in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

### Case 2 requires move construction prior to C++17

The language requires that a move-constructor exist for code of `X x = X{}` -- otherwise the code will fail to compile.

For example, using a `Person` class defined like:

```cpp
class Person{
public:
    ...
    Person(Person&&) = delete;
    ...
};
```

will fail to compile on statements like:

```cpp
Person p = Person{}; // Case 2
```

Example on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jfM11h)

**Note:** that the above code is completely valid in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and onward due to wording changes that allow for objects to be constructed directly in their destination address even when immovable and uncopyable (this is what people often refer to as "guaranteed copy elision").

### Case 3 is a lifetime extension of a temporary

The third case is a construction of a temporary whose lifetime is extended by being bound to an rvalue-reference. Lifetime of temporaries can be extended under certain cases where they are bound to either rvalue references or `const` lvalue references. For example, the following two constructions are equivalent in that they bind to a temporary's lifetime:

```cpp
Person&& p3_1 = Person{};
const Person& p3_2 = Person{};
```

As far as scoping rules go, this has the same lifetime as any other automatic variable (e.g. it will invoke a destructor at the end of the scope in just the same way as `Person person{}` will). However what can be done with construction, at least in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), is *quite different* from `Person p2 = Person{}` in that this code *will always compile* even if a move constructor is not present (since this is a reference binding).

For example, lets consider an immovable, uncopyable type like `std::mutex`. In *C++17* it's valid to write code of:

```cpp
std::mutex mutex = std::mutex{};
```

But in *C++11* that fails to compile. However, you *are* free to write:

```cpp
std::mutex&& mutex = std::mutex{};
```

Which creates and binds a temporary to a reference whose lifetime will be the same as any scoped variable constructed at that point.

Example on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/EnKbeT).

**Note:** Intentionally propagating lifetime of a temporary object is not commonly an intentional thing to do, but back before C++17 this is the only way to achieve an almost-always-auto syntax with immovable objects. For example, the above could be rewritten: `auto&& mutex = std::mutex{}`

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** - with respect to how construction will occur, and how the constructed variable behaves; but **No** with respect to the variable's type.

The compiler does not use assignment in any of these cases, i.e. it just has your program default-construct. You can use this code to verify:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Person {
    Person& operator=(Person&) {
       std::cout << "Assignment: operator=(Person&)\n";  return *this; 
    }
    Person& operator=(Person&&) { 
       std::cout << "Move assignment: operator=(Person&&)\n";  return *this; 
    }
    Person(const Person&) { std::cout << "Copy ctor: Person(Person&)\n"; }
    Person(Person&&) { std::cout << "Move ctor: Person(Person&&)\n"; }
    Person() { std::cout << "Default ctor: Person()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "P1:\n";
    Person p1{};
    std::cout << "Address of P1: " << &p1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "P2:\n";
    Person p2 = Person{};
    std::cout << "Address of P2: " << &p2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "P3:\n";
    Person&& p3 = Person{};
    std::cout << "Address of P3: " << &p3 << '\n';
}
```

See it on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/sPdesh).

The behavior for the third statement was a bit surprising to me; I actually though the compiler might reject it outright. Regardless - **Please don't declare rvalue references like that**. It's confusing to readers - even to me and almost certainly not what you want to be doing. I was certain that `p3` behaves like an rvalue reference; but - that's not actually the case, apparently: Despite having type `Person&&`, it [will](https://godbolt.org/z/TWYEx4) behave like an lvalue reference when passed to a function.

Comment: What _does_ the last case do/mean wrt variable type?

Comment: The third variant is safe, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of `p3` the only difference is the type. It is equal to a r-value parameter bound to a temporary argument i.e. it's l-value.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: Yes. Fixed.

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage: No, because I didn't compile with any optimization; and - no elision is possible, since I added side-effects (`std::cout` ops).

Comment: Your last statement is very strange. `p3` itself would be a lvalue where used despite being of type `Person &&` at declaration site, it needs to be `std::move`d to be used as a rvalue reference.

Comment: @bipll:  `std::is_same_v<decltype(p3), Person&&>` evaluates to true. Can you clarify?

Comment: Clarify what exactly?

Comment: @bipll: Why you wrote that a `p3` would need to be move()'d to be an rvalue reference.

Comment: Because `p3` as an expression is itself a lvalue, eh?

Comment: @bipll: So why is its type `Person&&` then?

Comment: So why not? Run some tests to see which overload is chosen if you pass it as an argument.

Comment: @einpoklum `p3` is an lvalue expression with the type `Person &&`, not an rvalue expression with type `Person`.

Comment: @Caleth: I was under the (apparently mistaken) impression that the a type can only correspond to a single value category...

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage: Equivalent in some aspects, not equivalent in others - although perhaps with bipll's comment, the equivalence is almost complete.

Comment: @einpoklum If I may, I think that Caleth is referring to the [if-it-has-a-name "rule"](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html).

Comment: "the variable you declared will be an r-value reference, so if you pass it to some function or assign from it - **a move will occur**" This isn't true at all. Any named reference is an **lvalue reference** even if it's declared an rvalue reference. This is why you must still call `std::move` or `std::forward` when dealing with reference parameters / variables

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that this question is tagged `c++11`, but the answer is only true for C++17. In C++11 `p2` requires either a move or copy constructor to be defined -- otherwise it will fail to compile

Comment: @Human-Compiler: If I change to C++11 at the GodBolt link, it still compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: But have correct the text regarding the behavior of `p3`.

Comment: @einpoklum If this were C++11 and the **move constructor were `delete`d**, then the behavior is different. Writing `Person p2 = Person{}` requires a move constructor ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/rbxhz3)). I'm just suggesting since this is tagged C++11 and is asking specifically about behavioral differences, that the answer should reflect it.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: It's weird, that the compiler requires the move ctor, but then allows itself to not actually use it... anyway, OP has not mentioned deleting the move ctor.

Comment: To be fair enough (from my point of view of course), a bounty of 100 will be awarded to this answer.

Comment: @NotAZoomedImage: I don't feel I deserve it actually - I learned a bunch from the comments myself.