# What is QString::QString(QString &&other) used for?

Tags: c++, qt, reference, qt5, qstring

I realized there exists another constructor besides normal QString::QString(QString &other). What is it used for? I cannot understand the type QString &&. Does it mean the reference to a reference variable? But the following code could not compile:

```
QString s1("abc");
QString &s3=s1;
QString &&s4=s3;
```

It complains "You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference"

Comment: it declares a rvalue reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11

Comment: Its a move constructor I belive.

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehMg6zvXuMY&ab_channel=TheCherno) explains it very well