# rvalue behaving as a lvalue

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue, lvalue

The below is a toy program I wrote to ask my question.

```
class Yo2 {
 public:
  Yo2() {}
  void foo2() && {}
};

void tmp(Yo2&& yo2) {
  yo2.foo2();
}
```

My compiler says

> 'this' argument to member function 'foo2' is an lvalue, but function
> has rvalue ref-qualifier

What am I missing? Why is yo2 being considered an lvalue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11

Comment: All variables are l-values. `yo2` is a r-value reference, but `yo2` itself is l-value.

Comment: Sorry @273K, I didn't understand your answer. You need to dumb it down to C++ noobs like me :-) What's the difference between r-value and r-value reference?