# What is && in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Address Operator? (&&)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549151/double-address-operator)

I came across the following function signature

```
void doSomething(double && r3);
```

It cannot be logical &&, and Reference is a single &... what is the above && ? If possible, can you point me to some documentation on it?

Comment: is r-value is a keyword in c++?

Comment: Not a keyword, but a concept. And the && is new to C++11. See the linked question.

Comment: Nope its a new addition in C++11, its designed to allow move semantics and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an rvalue reference. I could tell you that I am an expert on the matter, but this is probably the most confusing aspect of C++ to me. Anyhow, here is a great explanation.

http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_03.html

Comment: Here are two articles from Microsoft that helped me understand the difference between lvalue and rvalue.  The second shows a good example of how rvalue could be used. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx