# Error: Label used but not defined when using && operator

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, operator-overloading

```
int main()
{
        int i = 0;
        int *p = &i;
        int *q = &&i;
        return 0;
}
```

When compiling this using `gcc` on `Linux`, I am getting the error

```
addr.c: In function ‘main’:
addr.c:6:2: error: label ‘i’ used but not defined
```

Why is the compiler treating `int i` as `label` and not integer? When do we use `&& operator`?

**EDIT**: Okay, I can somewhat understand the answers, but can you explain the below macro definition from "arch/arm/include/asm/processor.h". It doesn't says anything about `label`, but the comment says, it can return the "`program counter`"

```
/*
 * Default implementation of macro that returns current
 * instruction pointer ("program counter").
 */
#define current_text_addr() ({ __label__ _l; _l: &&_l;})
```

Comment: What should `&&i` do? It's not like the pointer to `i` needs to be stored somewhere. You could try `int *q = &p`.

Comment: `&&i` makes about as much sense as `&5`. You can't get the address of an rvalue.

Comment: @Pubby remember maximal munch! `&&i` will never get parsed as `&(&i)`. (also, consider the dreaded overloaded unary `operator&` :P)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I know, but OP clearly intends `& &`.

Comment: I thought that too, but `q` is not an `int**` so I am not really sure.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? The error message says it all, you are trying to interpret `i` as a label, `&&` aplies to labels. So what is your question?

Comment: Did you want C or C++? You tagged both.

Comment: @JensGustedt The question is quite clear. I never saw this, and as it turns out, it is a gcc extension.

Comment: The `current_text_addr` macro defines the label `_l` and then evaluates to the address of that label. Since the label is where the macro is, its address is where the program is currently executing, also known as the program counter. The macro uses compiler extensions; it is not standard C and will not be portable. `__label__` declares a label that is local to the current block (the statements between `{` and `}`). This prevents `_l` from interfering with other variables named `_l`. Then `_l:` defines the label. Then `&&_l;` is an expression statement that is the address of the label.

Comment: The `({` and `})` are a compiler extension that allow multiple statements inside an expression. Its value is the value of the last statement inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What && operator? There is no unary && operator in C++. GCC has an extension that allows [computed goto](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) statements, and that extension uses && to get the address of a label.

Answer (score 10):

Here `&&` is the GNU C label address operator.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

```
int *q = &&i;
```

`i` must be a label. You have no label `i` in your program.

Example of a label:

```
int main(void)
{
    i:
    (void) 0;

     int i = 0;
     int *p = &i;
     int *q = &&i;
     return 0;
}
```

I added the `(void) 0;` statement as labels in C can only put before statements and not before declarations.

Comment: This answer is not useful. Why should `i` be a label? The example does not clarify that a bit.

Comment: This answer is correct. `&&` is used by `gcc` to get the address of a label. Why the downvote?

Comment: @alk it does (did) not explain what `&&` does or that it's `gcc` specific.

Comment: @JanDvorak The question is tagged with gcc.

Comment: @JanDvorak Just reload ...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that labels and variables exist in different scopes (name spaces) in standard C, and that is why this code would compile, even though there is a label i: and a variable int i with the same names.

Comment: "*... added the (void) 0; ...*": wouldn't a single `;` do also? Also if I remember correctly labels do not need to be declared in the source **before** their address is taken but simply somewhere.

Comment: @alk yes `;` would probably be ok as it is the null statement. Same for the `{}` statement.

Answer (score 4):

`&` is used two ways, first, you can get the address of a variable:

```
int *p = &i; // that's fine, p points to i's address
```

Second it's used to do a "bit-wise" and:

```
int i = 1;     // 01
int j = 3;     // 11
int k = i & j; // 01
```

`&&` is a logical operator, not an "address of address of" operator, it's use is in checking two conditions together and asserting that both are true.

```
if (something && something_else)
```

---

**EDIT:** I just noticed you taged this as C and C++... if this is a C question, see above. If this is a C++ question there's another note on `&&`:

[C++ Double Address Operator? (&&)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549151/double-address-operator)

---

**EDIT 2:** There's another use of the `&&` as a label value operator to take the address of the label.

This is what the error message is about since the compiler is assuming that's what you wanted to do:

The label value operator && returns the address of its operand, which must be a label defined in the current function or a containing function. The value is a constant of type void* and should be used only in a computed goto statement. The language feature is an extension to C and C++, implemented to facilitate porting programs developed with GNU C.

```
int main()
{
   void * ptr1;
   label1: ...
   ptr1 = &&label1;

   ...

   if (...) {
      goto *ptr1;
   }
   ...
}
```