# warning: taking the address of a label is non-standard

Tags: c++, g++, goto

Can anyone explain how the following code creates a label?

```
char memory[] = "hello";
&&memory[0];

error: label 'memory' used but not defined
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: You definitely got one `&` too much there, where the label stuff is coming from I don't know though.

Comment: @oli take the address of memory... if &memory[0] == memory.

Comment: @user4032914: The address of `memory` is just `memory` - it will decay to a pointer to the first character.

Comment: It's a GNU extension -- or, at least, addresses of labels are a GNU extension, and they use the `&&` notation. See [Labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values) in the GCC documentation.

Comment: Same as this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915121/error-label-used-but-not-defined-when-using-operator

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Although to be clear, `&memory` is not the same thing as `memory` (or `&memory[0]`).

Comment: @user4032914 `&memory[0]` gives you a temporary char pointer pointing to the first element. But you can't take the addresses of temporaries so the second `&` is illegal.

Answer (score 6):

```
&&memory[0];
```

That's not valid C++, thus a conforming extension can assign any semantics one could want to it.

It so happens, that `&&label` is the GNU folks' way of taking the address of a label for computed goto's, a GNU extension.

That's it.

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html

Comment: The whole meaning of the expression to the GNU compiler is that first the (undefined) label `memory` is resolved to an address [(of type `void *`)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) and then this pointer is subscripted via the `[0]` part, which happens to be an invalid operation too.  (You might want to include the link in your answer.)

Comment: Well, certainly they also have that irritating extension of allowing pointer-arithmetic on `void*` (I think that's not a conforming extension for c++).

Comment: Oops, `[]` actually seems to bind more tightly than `&&` and `(&&label)[0]` crashes GCC 4.9.0.