# type&& syntax in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Address Operator? (&&)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549151/double-address-operator)

In the reference for the vector class: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ I just noticed a strange syntax with two ampersands after the type name, e.g. in the constructor:

```
vector (vector&& x);
```

what does it mean and how does it work?

Comment: [move semantics; rvalue references](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval).

Comment: this is a move constructor, from the client side usage of vector does not change (and that's why it is so cool :))