# Meaning of && in the context of bitwise_cast<void*>(&&__opcode);

Tags: c++, webkit

I am looking at the code below which comes from JavascriptCore and I don't know what the meaning of the && is in the context below. An address of an address does not really make sense.

So can someone explain what the && means in the context below.

(the bitwise_cast uses a union to avoid strict aliasing problems that come with a reinterpret_cast)

The code below compiles on clang (and presumably gcc) but does not compile on our own proprietary C++ compiler.

The full source can be found [here](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/llint/LowLevelInterpreter.cpp).

```
#if ENABLE(COMPUTED_GOTO_OPCODES)
    Opcode* opcodeMap = LLInt::opcodeMap();
    #define OPCODE_ENTRY(__opcode, length) \
    opcodeMap[__opcode] = bitwise_cast<void*>(&&__opcode); //<---- The double && 
    FOR_EACH_OPCODE_ID(OPCODE_ENTRY)
    #undef OPCODE_ENTRY

    #define LLINT_OPCODE_ENTRY(__opcode, length) \
        opcodeMap[__opcode] = bitwise_cast<void*>(&&__opcode);

    FOR_EACH_LLINT_NATIVE_HELPER(LLINT_OPCODE_ENTRY)
    #undef LLINT_OPCODE_ENTRY
#endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549151/c-double-address-operator ? (If not, you may want to look into this if you haven't already)

Comment: @ChrisSprague: No, that's a different use of `&&` in a type specifier, to denote an _rvalue_ reference. Here, it's used as an operator in an expression.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yikes - that makes 3 completely different interpretations of `&&` in C++. Scary! Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @ChrisSprague: Only two in standard C++, since this is an extension. But there are three meanings of `&`. And several meanings of `static`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a GCC extension: [computed goto](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).

Given a `goto` label

```
label:
```

in standard C++, you can only jump to it directly:

```
goto label;
```

but GCC allows you to store its address with a non-standard use of `&&` as a unary operator (analogous to `&` for taking the address of an object, function, or member):

```
void * ptr = &&label;
```

and use that pointer later:

```
goto *ptr;
```

It looks like you can disable this through the preprocessor, for your compiler which doesn't have this extension. It will use some scheme based on a `switch` statement instead of computed jump label.