# difference between copy constructors?

Tags: c++

I am reading C++ Primer and this piece of code confuses me a little. Maybe i have read before but forgotten what its about.

this code has 2 copy constructors but i dont know what the difference is between them

```
class Quote {
public:
    Quote() = default;
    Quote(const Quote&) = default;    // <<== this one
    Quote(Quote&&) = default;         // <<== and this one
    Quote& operator=(const Quote&) = default;
    Quote& operator=(Quote&&) = default;
    virtual ~Quote() = default;
}
```

what is the difference in general?

and what do the double "&" mean?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4549167/2899559) answer.

Comment: copy constructor and move constructor.

Comment: thnx! i just remembered.. the RValue reference is for moving items that are about to be destroyed

Answer (score 4):

They are not both copy constructors, only the first one: `Quote(const Quote&) = default;`. The second one is a *move constructor*, do some reading on move semantics and C++11.

Comment: ``Quote(const Quote&) = default;`` is the copy constructor. ``Quote& operator=(const Quote&) = default`` is the assignment operator. ``Quote(Quote&&) = default`` is the move constructor. ``Quote& operator=(Quote&&) = default`` is the move operator.

Comment: hmmm i see... although in the piece of code it states "// memberwise copy" So thats what confused me. But i got it now,, thnx