# Why program didn't crash when lifetime of temporary has ended?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

Given the code below, it will give a warning:

> warning: a temporary bound to 'Foo::b' only persists until the
>   constructor exits [-Wextra]

```
struct Bar {
    inline void print() const { std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl; }
};

struct Foo {
    Foo() : b{} {}                    // create temporary
    void print() const { b.print(); } // OK but I'm expecting a crash here
    Bar&& b;
};

Foo f;     // Expecting lifetime of temporary ends here
f.print(); // OK - prints "Bar"
```

I am expecting accessing `Bar::print()` via `Foo::b` will lead to crash after `Foo`'s constructor exits.

How come the program still calls `Bar::print()` without a crash?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. This even may mean, it works or seems to work.

Comment: You've just proved by evidence that undefined can be unexpected.

Comment: is `Bar&& b;` a dangling pointer?

Comment: According to [SO: C++ Double Address Operator? (&&)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4549167/7478597) a dangling rvalue reference. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff However, references can't be null right? how come it can be dangling?

Comment: Since `Bar` is not polymorphic and has no data members, there is nothing for the reference to point to, dangling or not.  Why should the compiler create a distinction between a valid reference to nothing and a dangling reference to nothing?  It's not obliged to create a crash just because it could.

Comment: @TrentP, can you refer me to the part of the specs that states that?

Comment: @codekaizer - This question has been mulled over and over and over on SO. Changing "pointer" to "reference" and hanging on to the difference between the two, doesn't make it a whole new question. It's been answered to death.

Comment: I resembled your sample in VS2013 knowing that any destroyed instance is filled with test patterns. For my surprise, I got similar warnings and it worked without crash in my case too. So, I realized on the 2nd glance that `Bar::print()` does not access any member. For all that, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: A "dangling" reference is really easy to build: `int *p = nullptr, &r = *p;` `r` is a reference to a.. (how should I call this?) ...non-existing instance.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I understand. I have just encountered this "dangling rvalue reference" today. not insisting it's a new question. just seeking clarifications.

Comment: Ultimately, yes a reference can dangle. More generally, any glvalue expression can end up not referring to a valid object because of human error. Once that happens, there's plenty of UB to choose from.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thank you. so based on your statement, is it safe to say that references can be null too?

Comment: IMHO, a reference should grant a "living" object (in opposition to a pointer which might be intentionally a `nullptr`). But it can happen as well as division by 0 (which probably is rarely done intentionally).

Comment: Yes and no. Formally references aren't pointers, and must be initialized with the identity of an object. But... like Scheff shows, you can break it by introducing UB elsewhere (say with a null pointer).

Comment: @StoryTeller, Scheff, thank you. added knowledge for today.

Comment: @codekaizer, that a class with no data members and no virtual methods will have no data associated with it?  If it had data, then what would it be?  While your code triggers undefined behavior, compilers do not produce their output at random.  There no reason to expect that a dangling reference to nothing should crash, absent a debugging option specifically meant to detect such a thing.  Precisely what is created with an object is not specified, but something like §9.5.1, about what can be in a class in a union, gives an idea of what is expected of a compiler.

Comment: @TrentP - "Since `Bar` is not polymorphic", if it's polymorphic, does it make a difference?

Comment: @codekaizer, yes.  A polymorphic class will have a some sort of pointer into a table of function pointers, to allow the compiler to know what virtual methods to call from a base class pointer.  It's why that "no polymorphic classes in a union" rule is there.  If `Bar::print()` were a virtual method one could create code that would likely crash calling a dangling reference.

Comment: @TrentP, that's something. thank you!